# Making All Elements Of An Array The Same

Tags: python

I am trying to choose the larger of the first and last elements of an array of `len(3)` and make that all the elements of the array:

```
def max_end3(nums):
    a = max(nums[0], nums[2])
    for i in nums:
        i = a
    return nums
```

Comment: And? What is your question?

Comment: ```[max(a[0], a[-1])] * len(a)``` ?

Comment: @Tomerikoo wow good point, there isn't even a question there. I need some coffee.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to return a new list that is the maximum of the first and last element?

In Python you can access the last element with `[-1]`.

so a solution that doesn't care about the length of the list(minimum one element to work) would look like this:

```
def set_list_to_max_of_first_last(nums):
    return [max(nums[0], nums[-1])] * len(nums)
```

What we do here is we use `[]` to create a new list with one element. Then we make the array as long as the original with identical entries.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating the list -

```
def max_end3(nums):
    max_elem = max(nums[0], nums[-1])
    n = len(nums)
    return [max_elem] * n

>>> l = [1,5,67,100]
>>> max_end3(l)
[100, 100, 100, 100]
```